# OSMdroid how to get screen coordinates?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am doing app on android using osmdroid. How I can get coordinates(top, bottom, left,right) of map which is shown on screen? 
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear what you're asking, but I think you're asking for the lat/lon bounding box.

```
BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox = mMapView.getProjection().getBoundingBox();
```

Comment: thanx but actully i need dynamicly get coordinates of my (top, bottom, left ,right) corners or sides(up,down,right,left) of screen, so i can detect to load or not another points.
I tried something like this:

 Projection proj = myMap.getProjection();
            GeoPoint topLeft = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels(0, 0);
            Log.i("Top Left",   topLeft.getLongitudeE6()+"a" );
And topLeft.getLongitudeE6() always 0, I do it in onCreate if it important

Comment: That doesn't really tell us whether the solution posted by @kurtzmarc works for you or not. In case it works you just need to subscribe to a scroll event I guess.

Answer (score 0):

"I do it in onCreate if it important" => Yes, it is.

In fact, you cannot access to a correct mapview bounding box in onCreate. 
This is "because the MapView's width and height is zero because it hasn't had onLayout called yet"

This is a (quite annoying) osmdroid issue, not fixed in v4.2.

In addition, when called in onCreate, setCenter is also not working properly in v4.2.

See more explanation and workarounds here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

In react-native I use the *onRegionChangeComplete* event (`onRegionChangeComplete={e => properties.regionChange(e)}`). This event returns the region of the MapView. So: *{"latitude": 4.50751184289841, "latitudeDelta": 0.09999884159289252, "longitude": -75.67515761717539, "longitudeDelta": 0.06322002503726765}*

So, if you need to calculate a polygon with the screen area, you should do the following:

```
regionChange = (e) => {    
    areaLoadData = [
        {
            latitude: e.latitude + e.latitudeDelta,
            longitude: e.longitude - e.longitudeDelta
        },
        {
            latitude: e.latitude + e.latitudeDelta,
            longitude: e.longitude + e.longitudeDelta
        },
        {
            latitude: e.latitude - e.latitudeDelta,
            longitude: e.longitude + e.longitudeDelta
        },
        {
            latitude: e.latitude - e.latitudeDelta,
            longitude: e.longitude - e.longitudeDelta
        },
    ]
}
```